# Return of API in JSON format

Tags: c#, json, python-3.x, rest, flask

Return of API in JSON format

I'm creating an API in Flask that returns a LIST of data found, I need to convert this list to JSON format and return it to be handled in a WindowsForm (C#) application. It's giving an error when returning the data, searching I found some answers using jsonify() and json.dumps(), but it doesn't work.

```
def buscaIndicados(codigo):

    query = f"SELECT idCliente, codIndicacao, dataVencimento, status FROM clientes WHERE codIndicado = '{codigo}'"

    conn = mysql.connector.connect(host=servidor,database=dataBase,user=usuario,password=senha)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
    row_headers = [x[0] for x in cursor.description]
    resultado = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()

    list_data = []
    for result in resultado:
        list_data.append(dict(zip(row_headers, result)))

    return jsonify(result=list_data)
```

**Database return:**

```
[{'idCliente': 8, 'codIndicacao': 123456789, 'dataVencimento': '2021-12-01 00:00:00', 'status': 0}, {'idCliente': 9, 'codIndicacao': 454121421, 'dataVencimento': '2021-11-25 00:00:00', 'status': 1}]
```

**ERROR:**

```
"The view function did not return a valid response. The"
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
```

Comment: First see what you're getting from the DB, what's in zip(row_headers, result), etc, then if you need a JSON string, then json.dumps(list_data) should be enough

Comment: I put the bank's return in the question, I had also tried json.dumps(), also the error.

Comment: DO NOT use f-strings or other kinds of formatting to put data in queries. This exposes you to SQL injection. Always use parametrized statements.

Comment: Well done, now check what's in list_data, what's in jsonify(result=list_data) and show us how you're calling this function.

Comment: @Ellie You opened my eyes, I was calling the searchIndicates() function and trying to execute the return to its C# app, in the route function that calls the searchIndicates() function I wasn't handling the return, I put json.dumps() in the function of route and everything was resolved. Starter error. Thanks.

Comment: @ThiefMaster I'm still learning about all this, could you please give an example in the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check what you're getting from the DB, what's in zip(row_headers, result), etc, then if you need a JSON string, then `json.dumps(list_data)` should be enough.